# Condition with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I use conditions in React Hooks?
I get this error:  Objects are not valid as a React child in cause of my {content}

```
let content = favorit ? (
    <MaterialIcons
        style={styles.icon}
        name={'favorite'}
        size={33}
        color={'red'}
        onPress={() => {
            setFavorit(_delFromDB(lokal.id));
        }}
    />
) : (
    <MaterialIcons
        style={styles.icon}
        name={'favorite'}
        size={33}
        color={'red'}
        onPress={() => {
            setFavorit(_saveToDB(lokal.id));
        }}
    />
);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => {
            return { content };
        },
    });
}, [navigation]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in your hook you're returning an Object.

Try this method:

```js
let HeaderRight = () => favorit ? (
    <MaterialIcons
        style={styles.icon}
        name={'favorite'}
        size={33}
        color={'red'}
        onPress={() => {
            setFavorit(_delFromDB(lokal.id));
        }}
    />
) : (
    <MaterialIcons
        style={styles.icon}
        name={'favorite'}
        size={33}
        color={'red'}
        onPress={() => {
            setFavorit(_saveToDB(lokal.id));
        }}
    />
);

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
    });
}, [navigation]);
```

Comment: It works, but why does it not lead to a re-render?
setFavorite should update the state, because I've used the useState Hook
const [favorit, setFavorit] = React.useState(false);

Comment: Edit your original post and add the full component code. I'll try to solve the problem. I don't have enough information on how your component works right now.

Comment: solved in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292565/set-method-for-usestate-hook-doesnt-re-render-used-hooks

Answer (score 0):

The Objects are not valid as a React child error might mean that a few different things are going wrong. For example, it could be because the items being rendered in the JSX Element are objects instead of primitives (so make sure you’re not passing an object where a primitive is expected).

If nothing else works you can try adding `import 'core-js'` 
in the index.js file of the project, at line 1