# set method for useState Hook doesn't re-render used Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

When I update my state using "setFavorite", it re-renders my Component but not the hooks, used in my component. 
In this case, React.useLayOutEffect isn't called when I update my state, but the alert("test") is called.

When I refresh using expo, it re-renders the useLayoutEffect Hook and everything works fine.

Do you have any solution for this?

```
const database = SQLite.openDatabase('favoriten.db');

export default function LokalDetailsScreen(props) {
const [lokal, setLokal] = React.useState(props.route.params.lokal);
const [favorit, setFavorit] = React.useState(false);
const [navigation, setNavigation] = React.useState(props.navigation);

React.useEffect(() => {
    database.transaction((transaction) =>
        transaction.executeSql(
            'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favoriten (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, lokalID           TEXT)'
        )
    );
    _retrieveData(lokal.id, setFavorit);
});

alert('test');

let HeaderRight = () =>
    favorit ? (
        <MaterialIcons
            style={styles.icon}
            name={'favorite'}
            size={33}
            color={'red'}
            onPress={() => {
                _delFromDB(lokal.id, setFavorit);
            }}
        />
    ) : (
        <MaterialIcons
            style={styles.icon}
            name={'favorite-border'}
            size={33}
            color={'red'}
            onPress={() => {
                _saveToDB(lokal.id, setFavorit);
            }}
        />
    );

React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    alert('re-render with: ' + favorit);
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
    });
}, [navigation]);

return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView} contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.large}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: lokal.titelbildURL }} />
            <Text>{lokal.name}</Text>
            <Text>{`Favorit: ${favorit}`}</Text>
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
);
}

function _saveToDB(id, setFavorit) {
database.transaction((transaction) => {
    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO favoriten (lokalID) VALUES (?)', [id], (_, result)     => {
        if (result.rowsAffected > 0) {
            console.log('zu Favs hinzugefügt:' + ' ' + result.rowsAffected);
            setFavorit(true);
        }
    });
});
}

function _delFromDB(id, setFavorit) {
database.transaction((transaction) =>
    transaction.executeSql('DELETE FROM favoriten WHERE lokalID = ?', [id], (_, result) => {
        if (result.rowsAffected > 0) {
            console.log('von Favs entfernt:' + result.rowsAffected);
            setFavorit(false);
        } else {
            console.log('nicht von Favs entfernt:' + result.rowsAffected);
            setFavorit(true);
        }
    })
);
}

function _retrieveData(id, setFavorit) {
var res = false;
database.transaction((transaction) =>
    transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM favoriten WHERE lokalID = ?', [id], (_, result) =>     {
        console.log('Zeilen mit diesem Lokal: ' + result.rows.length);
        if (result.rows.length > 0) {
            console.log('fav auf true gesetzt');
            setFavorit(true);
        } else {
            console.log('fav auf false gesetzt');
            setFavorit(false);
        }
    })
);
}
```

Some Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Comment: `favorit` is not a dependency of `useLayoutEffect`, only `navigation` is. If you want the effect to be linked to `favorit` as well you have to include it in the dependency array.

Comment: also be aware that your `useEffect` hook runs on EVERY rerender, if you want it to run only once, use an empty array of dependencies: `useEffect(callback, [])` this way useEffect will only run once as `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` hooks get a second parameter of dependent state which will be used to evaluate if the hook has to rerun.

`useEffect(callback, dependencies)`

`useLayoutEffect(callback, dependencies)`

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

So in your example make sure that `favorit` is included in the list of dependencies of the `useLayoutEffect`:

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    alert('re-render with: ' + favorit);
    navigation.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
    });
}, [navigation, favorit]);
```